# Start a new process and share an object to it (shared memory)

Tags: python, subprocess, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

Can a process #1 start a process #2 with `Popen`, and pass to it a reference to a dict `D`, so that process #2 can read its content?

```
# process1.py
import subprocess, time
D = {'foo': 'bar'}
subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'process2.py', str(id(D))])
time.sleep(3600)

# process2.py
import sys
ref = sys.argv[1]  # can we turn this address into an (at least read-only) object?
                   # and read foo/bar?
```

If not, I know `sockets` (and more generally messaging techniques involving networking), `/dev/shm` on Linux,  and these [IPC techniques](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) to make 2 different processes communicate, but are there even simpler solutions by **just sharing an in-memory object**?
I guess, for security reasons, the processes should be started with a special option to authorize its memory to be shared with other processes.

Comment: Python's standard objects like dicts can't be shared directly with memory sharing.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a list of strings. You need to refactor *process2.py* so that you can import a function from it to which you pass whatever type of object you want and you will not *necessarily* need to create a new process.

Comment: Can you give an example @Booboo? In my real code, I do have 2 different processes (and this cannot be changed, one is a worker, the other is a webserver), I am curious if there is some way for process #1 to share an in-memory object with process #2.

Comment: A dict *isn't* "an in-memory object".  It's an arbitrarily large number of in-memory objects, interconnected via pointers.  Nothing less than the entire working memory of the Python process would give you full access to the dict.

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve? It seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) on the surface

Comment: @Marat The global question is about sharing objects between 2 processes. I know a few IPC methods from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html) but I was curious if there are ways by just sharing the memory objects directly, rather than passing data through sockets, etc.

Comment: @Basj is this interest abstract? because assumptions about the object structure are important here

Comment: @Marat Yes it is rather abstract, just to know more about general possibilities. We can assume for this question that the object is a list of 1000 strings (total size ~ 1GB) or a dict of a similar size.

Comment: @Basj then the TLDR is: by placing objects in shared memory you give up standard library memory management on them, making handling any non-trivial data structure rather impractical. Anything with variable length is non-trivial for this purpose, including both a list of strings and a dict. A fixed length byte array would be manageable, though

Comment: @Marat This is interesting, maybe can you post this as an answer with an example for fixed-length byte array?

Comment: @Basj [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory) provides some primitives - actually, including a shared list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, it seems [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap) is perfect for this (but note that it will not share an object but just `bytes`. `pickle` can be used for the serialization though).

> To map anonymous memory, -1 should be passed as the fileno along with the length.

> tagname, if specified and not None, is a string giving a tag name for the mapping. Windows allows you to have many different mappings against the same file. If you specify the name of an existing tag, that tag is opened, otherwise a new tag of this name is created.

Thus, this is a very simple shared-memory inter process communication without using a socket:

Server:

```
import mmap, time
mm = mmap.mmap(-1, 20, tagname="foo")
while True:
    mm.seek(0)
    mm.write(str(time.time()).encode())
    mm.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Client:

```
import mmap, time
mm = mmap.mmap(-1, 20, tagname="foo")
while True:
    mm.seek(0)
    buf = mm.read(128)
    print(buf)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note: this is only for Windows:

> Avoiding the use of the tag parameter will assist in keeping your code portable between Unix and Windows.

Another example with video data: https://github.com/off99555/python-mmap-ipc